# Pandas select rows based on randomly selected group from a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataframe

```
> df = C1. C2.  C3
>      a.  1.   2
>      a.  3.   5
>      b.  6.   7 
>      c.  0.   1 
>      b.  2.   3
>      a.  3.   1
```

I want to randomly select a value from C1 and take all its rows.
So if I select 'a' I will have:

```
df = C1. C2.  C3
     a.  1.   2
     a.  3.   5
     a.  3.   1
```

How can I do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sample.html) for one element Series with random value of column `C1` and then select all values in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df.C1.isin(df.C1.sample(n=1))]
print (df1)
   C1   C2  C3
0  a.  1.0   2
1  a.  3.0   5
5  a.  3.0   1
```

Answer (score 0):

You shuffle the dataframe (sample) and then take all the rows with the same value at the first row C1:

```
df[df['C1'] == df.sample(frac=1).iloc[0,0]]
```